# How can I prevent res.send() from overwriting the entire document?

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I am firing an ajax call that handles the insertion of users into the database.

I want to return a string or status code to the ajax success for further use.

If I use res.send() server side it overwrites the current document and display the response in the top left in a black document.

I tried using return but that didn't work either, unless I'm doing something wrong.

**Client Side**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/register",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);  
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Success!",
        text: "All good",
        icon: "success",
      });
    },
    error: function (e) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Error!",
        text: "There was an error saving to the database",
        icon: "error",
      });
      console.log(e);
    },
  });
```

**Server Side**

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  req.body = sanitize(req.body);

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  try {
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).send("Success");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send("Error");
    // Implement response to the user if for some reason the save failed
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this ajax being done inside a form submit perhaps? The symptoms don't make sense for an ajax request. Also the route shown has no `send()`

Comment: Sorry that was the latest method I tried. I updated the question to what I tried originally. And yes the submit button calls a js function that does some input validation and the submits the document.

Comment: So the problem is more likely that you aren't preventing the default form submit and page is reloading. Show us the submit code and can you confirm page reloads?

Answer (score 0):

I had the ajax call wraped in a function that I didn't call anywhere and I was just doing a regular form submit as the default. CLOSED